# Laravel Eloquent Dirty Checking Carbon Dates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `published_at` field in my model that I setup as a carbon date.

```
class Model {

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    ....

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($val)
    {
         $this->attributes['published_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($val));
    }
}
```

This is a filed settable by the user. When I run a `dirty` check on it:

```
$article->fill($data);
echo $article->isDirty() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

It always comes up `dirty`. Am I doing something wrong or is this because it's trying to compare two Carbon objects?

Comment: Not related to the problem but you can use `Carbon::parse($val)` instead of `Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($val))`

Comment: You don’t need to create a mutator method, Laravel will automatically convert it to a `Carbon` instance if the attribute name is in the `$dates` property.

Comment: I think Martins observation is probably the reason why it's dirty. All attributes in the $dates array are automatically converted to Carbon, so could be delay between the instantiating of this model and the manual set*Attrbitue be causing this to be marked as dirty?

Comment: Same frustration here.  It's "dirty" because the isDirty function is comparing the original value in the database (prior to casting it to a date in the model) against the new Carbon value.  To me, this should be considered a bug because for example if you have a "date" (not datetime or timestamp) field in the database the original value will always be a 'yyyy-mm-dd' string, but after casting to date, it will always compare against 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' no matter what you do.  Basically looks like we will have to NOT cast the field, and manually parse into a Carbon object if needed.

Answer (score 5):

This is now fixed with [Laravel 5.5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/282534f39c6eae39caf4f96f003b0aca696a7973/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1007-L1009).

For everyone using an older Laravel version:

Just overwrite your `getDirty()` method like this:

```
public function getDirty()
{
    $dirty = parent::getDirty();

    foreach ($dirty as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->original)) {
            continue;
        }

        // unset any non-changed date values
        if ($this->isDateAttribute($key)) {
            $old = new Carbon($this->original[$key]);
            $new = new Carbon($value);

            if ($old->eq($new)) {
                unset($dirty[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $dirty;
}
```

Comment: In my Laravel 5.4 app, a specific MySQL timestamp field was not identified as a Date Attribute with isDateAttribute mehtod, so I had to change that check to if($key == 'field_name' and $this->original[$key] == $value).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this in the end is to just properly format the date in mysql format and let Laravel handle the rest.

So before inputting the date:

```
$data['published_at'] = '2015-03-03'; // format here;
```

Even when hardcoding the date string in the `setPublishedAtAttribute` method it seems to always trigger the dirty flag to `true`.